# Monsters vs You /Dragons/ How to give them better resistance against firearms

Tags: science-based, armors, bio-mechanics

Before we start, no, I'm not stupid, I know that I need this, agility and magic together to level the playing field, but one at a time.

As I mentioned before, dragons can [synthesize](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/141497/32097), [break down](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2018/08/180823113613.htm), and thus effectively utilize graphene in their bodies.

Here's their size:
[image]
*Human on the picture is 180 cm tall, some proportions don't accurately represent my dragon (that jaw is criminally small)*

So, when I say resistance, I mean damage reduction (DR), i.e: the bullets are stopped by the dragon's armor. I obviously don't expect them to withstand anti-material rifles and such, I have the [That's my JAMMED] spell for those.

**So, how could the dragon's armor withstand sustained fire?**

Judgment process: I lay out criteria, in priorities, the answer that meets the highest, or the highest and the most of the other ones, wins.

Priorities:

- It should withstand the highest possible caliber, multiple times on the same spot. Of course, dragons are fast but I'm assuming a worst-case scenario.
- Light, it should be light.

Remember, graphene, though being able to disperse kinetic energy 10 times better than steel, is a **reinforcing material**. DON'T use it in itself, please!

So, I guess it's a duplicate, after all, [beep] Ok, so, I guess we could go with the mantis shrimp's club as a basis.

Comment: Didn't you already post that question ?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T When? What?

Comment: Highest possible calibre is a bit hard. Do you mean handheld weapon? If you are talking antitank weaponry, it is likely not possible

Comment: @Whitecold The emphasis is on multiple times, I don't know what the highest caliber, it can stop, is

Comment: Also, see the results of [searching for "natural armor"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22natural+armor%22+is%3Aquestion).